# PHP preg_match_all regex expression weirdness

Tags: php, regex

I am having some trouble with regex in php (preg_match_all).

I am using the following code to find an email encapsulated by <>:, i.e. :

```
preg_match_all("<[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})>:", $body,$matches);
```

For some reason PHP is blowing up at the colon with the following error:

> Warning:  preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier ':' in...

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am no regex guru, and am just about out of hair to pull.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use delimeters EX:

```
preg_match_all('/<[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})>:/', $body,$matches);
```

See the `/` I added on both ends telling PHP where the regex starts and ends.

Comment: that returned the following: Warning:  preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: how do I get the email address to return as a whole, and not individual pieces in the array?

Comment: @SuperMykEl `$matches[0]` will contain the whole match. `$matches[1-3]` will contain pieces. Just look at $matches[0] :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [T-Regx](https://t-regx) which **doesn't need** `/` at the start and end

```
$pattern = "<[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})>:";

$matches = Pattern::of($pattern)->match($body)->all();
```